# applying functions on all data frames which are element of a list and then clubbing modified data frame

Tags: r, function, merge, dataframe

`mylist` is a `list` object.
`mylist[[1]]` to  `mylist[[1000]]` are 1000 `data.frames`.
Each `data.frame` has same number of columns.

Function `decomp` is defined which can modify the `data.frame` by adding one column (Input: `data.frame`, output: `data.frame`)
Then we have to modify all the `data.frames`  and then, we have to merge them together. How can we do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "club together"? You should provide a reproducible example with the inputs you have and the output you want. Else, it is very difficult to help you...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question.

```
#create dataframes
a<-data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3), col2=c(4,5,6) )
b<-data.frame(col3=c(6,7,8), col4=c(9,10,11) )
c<-data.frame(col5=c(12,13,14), col6=c(15,16,17) )

#create the list with dataframes
mylist<-list()
mylist[[1]]<-a
mylist[[2]]<-b
mylist[[3]]<-c


#create funcion that add a column
decomp<-function(df,col) { return(data.frame(df,newcol=col)) }

#column to add
column<-c('x','y','z')

#add a column to each data.frame
mylist<-lapply(mylist,decomp,col=column)

#to merge the tables
    data<- mylist[[1]]
for (i in 2:length(mylist)) {
data<-merge(data,mylist[[i]],all=T,by="newcol")
}
```